# Which console email client is the best for counting emails?

Tags: email, console

I am preparing a special ranking websites of some kind. This ranking will be dynamically updated. One of thing which I want to evaluate is amount of emails which each website send in their newsletter. I want to count number of email sent in last 30 and 90 days.

I wonder which email client will be the best for such thing...

Comment: use fetchmail and count them with a script.

Answer (score 1):

You want to count the amount of newsletters you received from the websites? I would never recommend to use an e-mail client and look up the amount manually.

A better solutions would be to use / register a domain and set up your own e-mailserver on a (virtual) server. For example, use Postfix. With Postfix you can create a pipeline to a script. In that script you could make a counter for every e-mailalias received. If you are familiar with Perl (or similar) it's quite easy to set up. Just follow a tutorial for setting up postfix with spamassasin, but replace spamassasin with your own daemon :) Ofcourse you can also outsource this with freelancer.com.

Just my suggestion.